# What is the difference between Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData and Microsoft.Data.OData and Microsoft.AspNet.OData?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am creating a RESTful service using Web API and Entity Framework with OData endpoints. The Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData and Microsoft.Data.OData and Microsoft.AspNet.OData packages seem to overlap, so I wasn't sure which one to use. What are the differences between them? What are the pros and cons of each?

Comment: Not to mention Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.dll. I am currently using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.dll with .NET 6, but it looks like I need classes called `DefaultODataSerializerProvider` and `ODataResourceSerializer` to customize serialization, but the first class only exists in `Microsoft.AspNet.OData`, not `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData`, while the second exists in both. I am terribly confused.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[`Microsoft.AspNet.OData`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.OData/) is the one you'll most likely want to use for a new project. It sets up Web API to use the OData 4 protocol.

[`Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData/) is the older package for OData v1-3. It has a dependency on some of the core OData pieces from [`Microsoft.Data.OData`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.OData/), which is the "ODataLib" package for OData v1-3. (The OData v4 version of this is [`Microsoft.OData.Core`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OData.Core/), which is a dependency of `Microsoft.AspNet.OData`.)

Comment: Hi, i'm playing around with webapi + odata and I was wondering why the package adds so many dependencies to the project ?

Microsoft.AspNet.OData (OK.)

Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions
Microsoft.OData.Core
Microsoft.OData.Edm
Microsoft.Spatial
System.Collections
System.Collections.Concurrent
System.ComponentModel
System.Diagnostics.Debug
System.Globalization
System.Linq
System.Linq.Expressions
System.Reflection
System.Resources.ResourceManager
System.Runtime.Extensions
System.Threading
System.Threading.Tasks

Comment: @spilote: I imagine it's because the OData and Web API libraries *use* those other libraries. It's probably more noticeable now because .NET Core broke a lot of those pieces out into separate libraries, whereas they used to be automatically included as part of the Base Class Libraries.