# Why System.Web.Http.OData was unlisted?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

the link below shows System.Web.Http.OData was unlisted :

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Web.Http.OData/

> The owner has unlisted this package. This could mean that the package is deprecated or shouldn't be used anymore.

.

And I know this package by watching this video which is published in 2014/09, when in it using

```
config.Routes.MapODataRoute("OData", "odata", GenerateEdmModel());
```

at time 17:16: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w-lQ4EW_Z9E#t=17m06s

.

Does anyone know why this package is unlisted?

And is it a good idea to learn to use this package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know why this package is unlisted?

I'm not sure why this has been unlisted, however that is the old version of OData, so it may be because of that. The new version is here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData/

> And is it a good idea to learn to use this package?

You should be using the latest version if possible

Comment: At the moment Microsoft.AspNet.OData namespace is currently using for ODataV4.

There are some details here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38774327/3707753